# How to return a table, rows or record from a function in PostgreSQL 9?

Tags: function, postgresql

I have a table called `person` which has `id,name,status` and I want to return rows as a result of a function with 1 parameter (name). 
Can anyone help me? Please make it easy, because im very noob in PostgreSQL.

This is my code from a normal function

```
create or replace function fn_list(vname varchar) returns void as $$
begin
    SELECT id,name,status from usuario WHERE name= vname;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I know I'm returning a void function but how can I do if I want a list of rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know that pipelined returns in Oracle does this, so I used that to find 'RETURN NEXT' from plpgsql:

[http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/007b01c6dc31$ae395920$0a00a8c0@trivadis.com](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/007b01c6dc31%24ae395920%240a00a8c0@trivadis.com)

Also on grokbase:

http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-performance/069kcttrfr/pipelined-functions-in-postgres

(Edit to add official documentation): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Killer, I will have to make use of this myself.

Editing one more time to add in some demo code (directly from postgresql.org documentation):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (fooid INT, foosubid INT, fooname TEXT);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2, 'three');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (4, 5, 'six');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAllFoo() RETURNS SETOF foo AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r foo%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM foo
    WHERE fooid > 0
    LOOP
        -- can do some processing here
        RETURN NEXT r; -- return current row of SELECT
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;

SELECT * FROM getallfoo();
```

Comment: as a result i get (1,name1,status1) that value is a text?

Comment: i want a result like this column 1 : id, colum2 : name, colum3: status .... no a one column with all the values separating by "," U_U please help me

Comment: sorry i dont see the last line select * from getAllfoo(); THANKS it works

Comment: Sorry I missed all your responses, I was in bed.

Answer (score 12):

Using a loop to return the result of a query is slow and inefficient. The overhead of PL/pgSQL is not even required for this.

The best solution is:

```
create or replace function fn_list(vname varchar) 
  returns table(id integer, name text, status text) 
as $$
  SELECT id,name,status 
  from usuario 
  WHERE name= vname;
$$ language sql;
```

*If* PL/pgSQL is needed because some other procedural code needs to run before the query, then `return query` should be used instead of a loop:

```
create or replace function fn_list(vname varchar) 
  returns table(id integer, name text, status text) 
as $$
begin
  -- do some work....
  return query
    SELECT id,name,status 
    from usuario 
    WHERE name= vname;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

---

Then call it using:

```
select *
from fn_list('Arthur');
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Also, it is important to invoke Table functions in the FROM clause, as shown above, and *not from the SELECT clause*.  The following compiles but can give unpredictable results : ```SELECT fn_list('Arthur') FROM some_table ```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here omit important parts of using functions. Here's an updated way of using functions in postgres (including declaration, variables, args, return values, and running). Below is an over-baked example of updating the tweet on the bottom right "blurb" with "hello world".

| id (serial) | pub_id (text) | tweet (text) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | hello world |
| 2 | def | blurb |

```
-- Optional drop if replace fails below.
drop function if exists sync_tweets(text, text);

create or replace function sync_tweets(
    src_pub_id text, -- function arguments
    dst_pub_id text
) returns setof tweets as -- i.e. rows. int, text work too
$$
declare
    src_id    int; -- temp function variables (not args)
    dest_id   int;
    src_tweet text;
begin
    -- query result into a temp variable
    src_id := (select id from tweets where pub_id = src_pub_id);

    -- query result into a temp variable (another way)
    select tweet into src_tweet from tweets where id = src_id;

    dest_id := (select id from tweets where pub_id = dst_pub_id);
    update tweets set tweet=src_tweet where id = dest_id;

    return query -- i.e. rows, return 0 with return int above works too
        select * from tweets where pub_id in (src_pub_id, dst_pub_id);
end
$$ language plpgsql; -- need the language to avoid ERROR 42P13

-- Run it!
select * from sync_tweets('abc', 'def');

/*
  Outputs
   __________________________________________________ 
  |  id (serial)  |  pub_id (text)  |  tweet (text)  |
  |---------------|-----------------|----------------|
  |  1            |  abc            |  hello world   |
  |  2            |  def            |  blurb         |
  --------------------------------------------------
*/
```